# How to define values in python constructor, so it can be used from method level

Tags: python, url, python-requests, endpoint, self

I am new to Python, so my requirement is to initialize the constructor with fixed properties, so I can later retrieve it, at the method level.
Like I want to initialize with URL and header properties, so I just require to pass endpoint for specific request to do my operation.
Sorry in advance, If my question creates a spam issue.

```
import requests

url = 'https://api.getpostman.com/'


class REQ:

    def __init__(self):
        self.header = {"X-Api-Key": "KEY Value",
                       "Content-Type": "application/json"}
        self.url = url
    
    def get(self, endpoint):
        result = requests.get(endpoint)
        rs_Code = result.status_code
        rs_Body = result.json()

        return [rs_Code, rs_Body]


obj = REQ()
obj.get('collections')
```

Comment: Use e.g. `def __init__(self, key, url):` to define parameters for the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

```py
import requests


class Req:

    def __init__(self, url, headers):
        self.headers = headers
        self.url = url
    
    def get(self, endpoint):
        result = requests.get(f"{self.url}/{endpoint}", headers=self.headers)
        rs_Code = result.status_code
        rs_Body = result.json()

        return [rs_Code, rs_Body]


obj = Req(
  url='https://api.getpostman.com',
  headers={
    "X-Api-Key": "KEY Value",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
)
code, body = obj.get('collections')
```

Comment: Thanks, @MetallimaX, there was a small tweak required to format the string, as Python 3.5 does not support f" ", so I just changed a bit.

```result = requests.get('{}/{}'.format(self.url, endpoint), headers=self.headers)```